# Spectrum of sum of weighted Wishart matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices

This is a [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3919741/87355) from mathstackexchange, as I think asking this question is more appropriate here.

Coming from statistical physics, I am interested in the (real) spectrum of the following sum, and ultimately $l_p$ norms of the spectrum,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^m c_n X_n, 
\end{equation}
where $c_n$ are non-random real numbers and $X_n$ are independent [Wishart matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) of size $m\times m$. Independent in the sense of elementwise independence. The weights $c_n$ are nice in the sense that the above sum is uniformly bounded with respect to $n$. Let the degree of freedom of the Wishart matrices be $p$. I am interested in the limit large $m$ and the cases where $p/m\to 0$ and $p/m\to$ constant > 0. I know that in the latter case, the spectrum of $X_n$ will be approximated by the [Marchenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution).

I am new to operator valued probability theory. I did some searching and could find results on spectra of A+B, where A and B are random (free) $m\times m$ matrices. Most of them where in the limit of large dimension $m$. I could not find something related to summing over orders of the dimension of the matrices $m$. Are there any results in that direction, maybe some kind of central limit theorem? If yes, where can I find them?

I am grateful for any advice and literature hints!

Comment: I am not completely sure I understand your parameters (there are many $p$'s), but I guess that, as in Rudelson's "Random vectors in the isotropic position." (JFA 1999)", you can obtain powerful estimates for the Schatten $p$-norms (=$\ell_p$ norm of the spectrum) by symetrization and using the non-commutative Khintchine inequalities.

Comment: Thanks @MikaeldelaSalle! Sorry for the confusion. The $p$ in $l_p$ is of course independent of the degree of freedom $p$. In Rudelson's paper, p64/65 where he states the Khintchine inequality, to what sequence are the Rademacher functions applied and what is $\|\cdot\|_{L^p(Q,\mu,C^n_p)}$ space?

Comment: I do not have the paper under my eyes, but I guess that $L^p(Q,\mu,C_p^n)$ is the space of size-n matrix-valued random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mu)$, for the norm $\|X\|^p = \mathbf{E} Tr( |X|^p)$.

Comment: The idea of symmetrization is that, for independant mean $0$ matrices $Y_i$, up to a factor $2$, the $L^p(\Omega,\mu,C_p^n)$-norm of $\sum_i Y_i$ is of the order the norm of $\sum_i (Y_i - Y_i')$, where $Y'_i$ are independant copies of $Y_i$. By independance, this last quantity as the same norm as $\sum_i \varepsilon_i (Y_i-Y'_i)$ for independant Rademacher $\varepsilon_i$. This is how rademacher functions come into the picture and how NC Khintchine can be used.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is addressed in [On the Exact and Approximate Eigenvalue Distribution for Sum of Wishart Matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00222). The approximation replaces the weighted sum of Wishart matrices by one equivalent Wishart matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I had a quick look into the reference you gave. There, the coefficients are assumed to be positive. I will see if I can generalize to real coefficients.

Comment: Another question: In the reference complex Wishart matrices are considered. I have not understood the proofs yet, so I can not say, in what sense they hold for real Wishart matrices as well. Or is this easily seen?

Comment: real or complex Wishart matrices is not an essential difference, the formulas will carry over; negative weights, however, is an essential difference; if you allow for negative weights the resulting matrix may no longer be positive definite, so this approximation of the weighted sum by an equivalent Wishart matrix will fail.

Comment: Thanks! I guess one can still make some use of that result by splitting the $c_j$'s into positive and negative and reduce the problem to the difference of just two wishart matrices.